# Querying a PostgreSQL database from Snowflake

Tags: postgresql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

PostgreSQL offers a way to query a remote database through dblink.

Similarly (sort-of), Exasol provides a way to connect to a remote Postgres database via the following syntax:

```sql
CREATE CONNECTION JDBC_PG
  TO 'jdbc:postgresql://...'
  IDENTIFIED BY '...';

SELECT * FROM (
  IMPORT FROM JDBC AT JDBC_PG
  STATEMENT 'SELECT * FROM MY_POSTGRES_TABLE;'
)

-- one can even write direct joins such as
SELECT
  t.COLUMN,
  r.other_column
FROM MY_EXASOL_TABLE t
LEFT JOIN (
  IMPORT FROM JDBC AT JDBC_PG
  STATEMENT 'SELECT key, other_column FROM MY_POSTGRES_TABLE'
) r ON r.key = t.KEY
```

This is very convenient to import data from PostgreSQL directly into Exasol without having to use a temporary file (csv, pg_dump...).

Is it possible to achieve the same thing from Snowflake (querying a remote PostgreSQL database from Snowflake with a direct live connection)? I couldn't find any mention of it in the documentation.

Comment: Snowflake does not support "database links". You may try to create an ODBC or JDBC driver from PostgreSQL to Snowflake.

Comment: Just a note...as much as people like to avoid intermediate files when loading data from one source to a Snowflake database, it is the most efficient way to get data into Snowflake.  Don't try to avoid that step.

Comment: @MikeWalton from Exasol, I can seamlessly query a PostgreSQL table from a remote AWS server (as demonstrated from my example above) and include that into a join (see edit). This methods fetches millions of rows (a few gigs of data) in a few seconds and performs the join in real-time, without any intermediate file. I fail to see see how one can get more efficient than that.

Comment: @Jivan I misunderstood the question.  I thought you were trying to load the data into Snowflake without dropping the data to a CSV?

Comment: That's effectively one of the use cases but for let's say bulk imports I understand the need to dump that into a parquet file on s3, no issue with that. However, I would have hoped that a database system as expensive as Snowflake would at least allow to query an external database in a direct manner, so that we don't have to maintain a whole pipeline just for that purpose, having to take care of when to update, etc. Snowflake is very expensive and doesn't seem to allow that, this is quite odd and not really pushing us towards choosing it in our evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using [external functions](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/external-functions-introduction.html)? It's not exactly what you're looking for (Snowflake doesn't have that capability yet) but it can be used as a workaround in some use cases. For instance, you could create a Python function on AWS Lambda that queries PostgreSQL for small amounts of data (due to Lambda limits) or have it trigger a PostgreSQL process that dumps to S3 to trigger Snowpipe for the bulk import use case.